# Find at least one solution in operation notation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find at least one solution:

$$(D^3+1)^5(D+1)^4(D-1)^4y=3e^t$$
In operation notation $(D^3+1)y=\frac{d^3y}{dt^3}+y, (D^3+1)^5$ is this operation done 5 times.

Maybe any ideas? I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(D-1)3e^t=0$, so performing the operation of $(D-1)$ creates
$$(D-1)(D^3+1)^5(D+1)^4(D-1)^4y=0$$
which is just a homogeneous equation, which I leave to you to solve. You'll get one more constant than you should however, so to take care of that plug in the general solution to the above to the original equation and you should be able to find the true solution.

The method described is called the annihilator method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint to get you started:

Note first that $(D-1)e^t=0$ so the $(D-1)$ term needs some particular attention, because there is an $e^t$ term on the right hand side, and the $(D-1)$ factor kills terms in $e^t$.

So notice that $(D-1)(t^re^t)=rt^{r-1}e^t$, from which you should be able to show that $(D-1)^4(t^4e^t)=24e^t$

Then $(D+1)e^t=2e^t$ and $(D^3+1)e^t=2e^t$

Put the pieces together and you should be able to find a solution.